# contain new elements of an "instance" in javascript

Tags: javascript

so I know there are tons of ways to simulate inheritance and other OO features.  I have chosen one to use for my project and am wondering if I can create an instance and add stuff to it and keep it contained (within braces).
Consider the following:

```
function BaseClass(){
  <this.stuff here>
}

function SubClass(){
  this.superClass = BaseClass();
  this.superClass();

  <this.other stuff here>
}

myObj = new SubClass();
```

so myObj is an instance of SubClass.  I can add things to myObj like:

```
myObj.blah = "funtimes";
```

What I would like is to be able to add stuff to the "instance" and keep it organized in braces much like the constructor.  psuedo code like:

```
myObj = new SubClass() {
  var blah = "funtimes"
  <more instance specific stuff here>
}
```

Is something like this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/With), but [I do not recommend it](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Still, a very powerful statement.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, I am familiar with with, and its pitfalls.  I am slightly hesitant to use it but not totally opposed.  It does sort of achieve what I want.

Hopefully I can get some other ideas too.
Thanks.